# Issue in uninstallation with "Uninstall previous installation action" on Mac

Tags: uninstallation, install4j

I have built an app which would uninstall any old installation if the app is installed in the same directory. For this I have used the action "Uninstall previous installation" action before start of installation. It is working fine on Windows and Linux but on Mac it is throwing the below error in the `installation.log` and does not install the older app at all.

```
INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.UninstallPreviousAction [ID 305]: Execute action
   Property installationDirectory: null
   Property onlyIfSameApplicationId: false
   Property rollbackSupported: true
   checking running processes
   checking running processes ok
   getting previous installation id
   starting uninstaller
```

Error

> com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.launching.LaunchHelper: return value is 1
>   [INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.UninstallPreviousAction$UninstallerThread: uninstaller process returned 1
>          see uninstallPrevious.log for the log file of the uninstaller

While searching for uninstallPrevious.log in the .install4j directory I don't fine it. Please advise on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in install4j 6.0 that this file is not copied to the .install4j directory on Mac OS X. This will be fixed in install4j 6.1. As a workaround you should be able to see the uninstaller log file in the temp directory. Execute

```
open $TMPDIR
```

in a terminal, sort by file modification time and look for file names starting with "i4jlog". One of them will be the log file of the uninstaller.

Comment: Thanks Ingo! I will try to get the uninstaller log but can you advise on why there is error on MAC? Is there an issue with the ""Uninstall previous installation" action on MAC? Because the same is working on Windows and Linux and I have only one project for WIndows, Linux and Mac.

Comment: I don't think there is a general issue on the Mac with the "Uninstall previous action". The problem on the Mac is only with the copying of the log file.

Comment: I tried to search the file starting with i4jlog in the $TMPDIR but I could not get any such file in the directory.

Comment: For a work around I can add an action "Run Script" in which I can delete the .app file with the code.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's "i4j_log", but I would just sort by time and look at the most recent file. If that does not work, please write to support@ej-technologies.com, and we will send you a pre-release version where the log file copying bug is fixed.

Comment: Actually I don't find any file corresponding to i4j or any log file. I sorted in by time only. Okay I will write a mail to the support team in this regard. Thanks!